# Where can you find such creatures?

Tags: riddle, word

My prefix can be geometrical,
My infix is a property of waves,
And my suffix may be a base.
My whole, double, hands or feet.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 9, accepted):

A guess:

> **webbed**

*My prefix can be geometrical,*

> web

*My infix is a property of waves,*

> ebb

*And my suffix may be a base.*

> bed

*My whole, double, hands or feet*

> **webbed** — could be a reference to spiders who has twice the limbs of humans which can double as either hands or feet.
>
>   **Edit:** Double refers to the length of the word (6) being two times that of each of its affixes (3). Also, some creatures may have *webbed* hands or feet (and hence the reference to the title).

Comment: You got it. In the last line "double" means the length of the word. PS: grats on 7k rep :-)

Comment: I’m still slightly unclear on the “double” part, though. PS: thanks a lot, @Randal'Thor! :)

Comment: @Randal'Thor Does the last line have anything to do with requiring more than one hand’s worth of fingers to count the length?

Comment: "double" refers to the length of the word compared with the prefix/infix/suffix. "hands or feet" and the title relate to the meaning of the word itself.

Comment: @Randal'Thor I have made the edit with reference to your comments. Am I still missing something?

Comment: No, this is fine, I'll accept it ... eventually ;-) I'm pretty slow at awarding checkmarks in general; don't worry about it.

Answer (score 7):

I know one correct answer has already been posted by Ébe Isaac, but I believe an alternative answer may be

> **polydactyl**

*My prefix can be geometrical*

> **poly**, as in [polygon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon)

*My infix is a property of waves*

> **dac** or **DAC**, describing a [digital-to-analog converter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digital-to-analog_converter).  Waves can be [analog or digital](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/analog-vs-digital/digital-signals).

*And my suffix may be a base*

> **tyl** or **TYL**, the [IATA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_airports_by_IATA_code:_T) code for the airport in [Talara, Peru](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talara), which hosted a United States air base during World War II.

*My whole, double, hands or feet*

> To be **polydactyl** is to have [polydactyly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polydactyly), which is the condition of having extra fingers or toes

*Where can you find such creatures?*

> Perhaps the [Black Lagoon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creature_from_the_Black_Lagoon)?  Any mutagens in that water may produce a *polydactyl* creature with *webbed* hands and feet.